# Keeping track of a global index of an array using a switch case

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a switch case in reducer file for a react-redux application. I need to track of a global index of an array and return next and previous item. The problem is based on current code as below. The init item showing as 'A' then on next it shows 'B' however after this point the index stuck on 1 (item B). Also for previous one index is undefined! How would you achive this using switch case?

```
export default function(state = {}, action){

const carousel =['A','B','C','D', 'E'];
let index = 0;

switch(action.type){
    case INIT_ITEM:
        return carousel[index];
    case NEXT_ITEM:
        index = index + 1;
        return carousel[index];
    case PREV_ITEM:
        index = index - 1;
        return carousel[index];
}

return state;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually store the `index` value in the state, you're storing the value at the carousel index instead.

Therefore every time your code is initiated, `index` is 0. To fix this, take the current `state` value, and find the corresponding `index` in `carousel`, or default to `0` where the value doesn't exist.

Also, you need to account for reaching the beginning and end of your array when calling the previous and next actions.

```
export default function(state = null, action) {
    const carousel =['A','B','C','D','E'];
    let index = Math.max(0, carousel.indexOf(state));

    switch(action.type){
        case INIT_ITEM:
            return carousel[index];
        case NEXT_ITEM:
            index = Math.min(index + 1, carousel.length - 1);
            return carousel[index];
        case PREV_ITEM:
            index = Math.max(index - 1, 0);
            return carousel[index];
    }

    return state;
};
```